# Why is my code slow in safari desktop only?

Tags: javascript, performance, debugging, browser, safari

I'm building a website that uses a few animations/libraries, AOS, simpleParallax and slick are the main ones. The website seems to run okay everywhere except Safari desktop. It runs fine in Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft edge, Opera, and it also runs fine in Safari on mobile, but it's extremely laggy, and choppy on Safari Desktop.

This is the function I use for the sliders on the 'services' and 'faq' pages

```
// slider
 (function () {
        var work = $('.js-work'),
            sliderWork = work.find('.js-work-slider');

        sliderWork.slick({
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            dots: false,
            arrows: true,
            prevArrow: sliderWork.parents('.js-work').find('.js-prev'),
            nextArrow: sliderWork.parents('.js-work').find('.js-next'),
            speed: 900,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 10000,
            responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 1024,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 3
                }
            }, {
                breakpoint: 768,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 3,
                    focusOnSelect: true,
                    vertical: true,
                    verticalSwiping: true
                }
            }]
        });
    })();
```

This is the parallax effect used throughout the website

```
// parallax effect
(function () {
    var parallax = $('.js-parallax');
    if (parallax.length) {
        parallax.each(function () {
            var _this = $(this),
                scale = _this.data('scale'),
                orientation = _this.data('orientation');

            new simpleParallax(_this[0], {
                scale: scale,
                orientation: orientation,
                overflow: true,
                delay: .6,
                transition: 'cubic-bezier(0,0,0,1)'
            });
        });
    }
})();
```

And this is an example of the css used for the AOS on the main title of the webpages. AOS is used quite a bit throughout the website, but I wouldn't say it's used an excessive amount at all.

```
.main__title[data-aos] p span {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(105%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(105%);
  transform: translateY(105%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s;
  -o-transition: transform 0.8s;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transition: transform 0.8s, -webkit-transform 0.8s;
}

.main__title[data-aos].aos-animate p span {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.main__title[data-aos].aos-animate p:first-child span:first-child {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.main__title[data-aos].aos-animate p:first-child span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.main__title[data-aos].aos-animate p:nth-child(2) span:first-child {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.6s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.6s;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}

.main__title[data-aos].aos-animate p:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.8s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.8s;
  transition-delay: 0.8s;
}

.main__title[data-aos].aos-animate p:nth-child(3) span:first-child {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
  -o-transition-delay: 1s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

I'm pretty much lost on how to fix this, it seems really strange that it runs fine in safari on mobile, but is completely broken on desktop. Please keep in mind this website is still very much a work in progress and that I'm a beginner, but I really want to find the solution to this problem before going any further with it.

If anyone is able to point out what I might be doing wrong, or can explain the ways Safari might operate differently from other browsers, I would really appreciate it!

here is the project https://secure-hollows-07774.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I explained in a comment on your previous question, it is not likely to be caused by your slider. I will copy paste it here.

Comment: Your issue with lag is caused by how you handle your animations. When you scroll you change translate etc. for every scroll event that is fired (which is fired for every pixel movement). For example, you have a delay of 0.6 seconds on the main background (green shape that moves left as you scroll). When you change the translate every 0.1 seconds due to scrolling you queue up a load of animations to happen that all overlap and this causes lag. If you throttle the scroll rate to match you animation speed it will fix the issue. I would go with 0.3s throttle and 0.3s animation to make it smooth.

Comment: sorry im not sure how i missed your first comment, so you're saying i should introduce a throttle function into my code? and then change the 'delay' in my parallax function to match the throttle at 300? thanks for your time i appreciate it

Comment: Yes try that, I mean it isnt guaranteed to be the cause but having had a similar issue in the past I would be 90% confident it is that. Give it a go and if it still doesn't work I will look into further for you.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I tried out lodash throttle and it didn't seem to solve the issue. I'm not entirely sure the issue is coming from the parallax though since i can remove the parallax function and it's still extremely laggy, and also the 'about' page uses the parallax function 6 times and runs smoothly compared to the 'services' and 'faq' page where the parallax is only used once

Comment: If you're still willing to take a further look into it would be greatly appreciated. I can offer a bounty on the question for you if you like, and if I can provide anything more for you like the github repo or anything please just let me know

Answer (score 1):

Just tried on Safari and it seems great on my end. Maybe try clearing the cookies in your browser?

Comment: Really? That's strange, I've tried clearing cookies and the cache and still had no luck. I also sent it to a couple friends earlier and they ran it on Safari and said it was super slow. I'm so confused

Comment: That's really weird. Not only did it load quickly but the animations were very fluid.

Comment: Maybe try this if you haven't yet?

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8257608?answerId=32936003022#32936003022

Comment: Thanks I'll try that out. That sounds like a solution to fix it on my end though, I'm still worried that it will be slow on other peoples computers. I know it worked well for you, but other people have said it's slow. What kind of computer are you using if you don't mind me asking

Comment: 2016 MB Pro - If you'd like I can try it on a 2013 iMac too?

Comment: My friends and I also have all tried on MB pros so it doesn't seem to be an issue with what machine is running it. Thank you though I appreciate your help